# How to get longitude and latitude of current location?

Tags: android, request, location, latitude-longitude

We are using SDK version 22 as our target but have set SDK 17 as minimum. In order to get the current location with coordinates displayed in a editText we used the following code:

[image]

Our problem has to do with the method requestLocationUpdates  because it requires that we cast 4 parameters as displayed on the image.

This is our build gradle:
[image]

After we cast them, there is no error in the code but after running our app we get the following message: application has stopped!

Here is our Android manifest:
[image]

Comment: you could not post your code instead of screenshots???

Comment: Use LogCat to examine your Java stack trace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this In addition, I echo the comments from Mariano: please paste text, not images. "Our problem has to do with the method requestLocationUpdates because it requires that we cast 4 parameters as displayed on the image" -- presumably, `this` does not implement the `LocationListener` interface, and therefore you are crashing as a result at runtime.